# Launching a window from AppDelegate is not recognised by toolbar, Touch Bar and menus

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying to programmatically launch a window from AppDelegate, specifically from Services Provider and it works but not very well because the toolbar doesn't work, Touch Bar doesn't show up and custom menu items I've added are disabled. The default menus and menu items provided by Apple works.

All my views are created on storyboards. The default main window is not launched from AppDelegate.

I launch the window like this.

```
guard let windowController = NSStoryboard.main?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: .windowController) as? WindowController else { return }

windowController.window?.title = data.title
windowController.viewController?.property = data
windowController.showWindow(self)
```

However, if I initiate by segue, it works perfectly.

```
guard let splitViewController = NSApp.mainWindow?.contentViewController as? NSSplitViewController,
      let viewController = splitViewController.splitViewItems[1].viewController as? ViewController else { return }

viewController.anotherViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: .segue, sender: data)
```

So, why don't I do that? Because it works from the main window and then that programmatic launched window prevent that code from working again. It only works when there is only one window.

I want it to work every single time. It doesn't matter if the main window is the key window or the subsequent other non-main windows.

How can I make sure that I can launch a window and it is also recognised by the toolbar, Touch Bar and the custom menu items and it doesn't matter if there is only the main window or other windows which are not the main window but different type of windows.

Comment: What is the target of the custom menu items? What do you mean by "recognised by the toolbar"? Is `windowController` deallocated when it goes out of scope?

Comment: The menu items are connected via first responder from the `NSWindowController` subclass, `@IBAction func ...`. The toolbar items doesn't work, I can click on them but nothing happens. They are not disabled similarly the Touch Bar doesn't show up. It is as if I did not implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by deallocated? The window disappear? They don't. The best I can describe is as if I forgot to connect the toolbar by delegate and that would make it functional. I haven't forgot because they are connected correctly on storyboard. Segue transition works perfectly but programmatically fails.

Comment: Is there something similar for non-document based app, like `NSDocumentController.shared.openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay(false)` and `NSDocumentController.shared.openDocument(withContentsOf: fileURL, display: true)`?

Comment: It sounds like the window controller is deallocated by ARC. AppKit keeps the window alive.

Comment: What can I do about it? Is it possible to make a window segue from itself? I have a main window which segue to another window and that window is what I want to instantiate multiple times.

Comment: `NSApp.mainWindow` is not always your main window. How about saving a reference to `NSApp.mainWindow` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Comment: I worked it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the `mainWindow` property, thinking it refer to the actual main window when it really point to the focussed window. So, the main window that I actually want is the first window from the `windows` array.

```
guard let mainWindowController = NSApp.windows.first?.windowController as? MainWindowController,
      let splitViewController = mainWindowController.contentViewController as? SplitViewController,
      let viewController = splitViewController.splitViewItems[1].viewController as? ViewController else { return }

viewController.anotherViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: .segueIdentifier, sender: data)
```

The menu items, toolbar and Touch Bar are working and responding to user interactions.